# Efficient way to select a subset of elements from a Seq in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a sequence

```
val input = Seq(1,3,4,5,9,11...)
```

I want to randomly select a subset of it. What is the fastest way.

I currently implement it like this:

//ratio is the percentage of the subgroup from the whole group

```
def randomSelect(ratio:Double): Boolean = {

   val rr=scala.util.Random
   if (rr.nextFloat() < ratio) true else false

}



val ratio = 0.3
val result = input.map(x=>(x, randomSelect(ratio))).filter(x._2).map(x=>x._1)
```

So I first attach a true/false label for each element, and filter out those false elements, and get back the subset of the sequence.

Is there any faster/ advantage way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are basically two approaches to this:

- select `n` elements at random
- include or exclude each element with probability `p`

Your solution is the latter and can be simplified to:

```
l.filter(_ => r.nextFloat < p)
```

(I'm calling the list, `l`, the instance of `Random` `r` and your ratio `p` from here on out.)

If you wanted to sample exactly `n` elements you could do:

```
r.shuffle(l).take(n)
```

I compared these selecting 200 elements from a 1000 element list:

```
scala> val first = time{
 | l.map(x => (x, r.nextFloat < p)).filter(_._2).map(_._1)
 | }
 Elapsed time: 3249507ns

scala> val second = time {
 | r.shuffle(l).take(200)
 | }
 Elapsed time: 10640432ns

scala> val third = time{
 | l.filter(_ => r.nextFloat < p)}
Elapsed time: 1689009ns
```

Dropping your extra two `maps`s appears to speed things up by about a third (which makes complete sense). The shuffle-and-take method is significantly slower, but does guarantee you a fixed number of elements.

I borrowed the timing function from [here](http://biercoff.com/easily-measuring-code-execution-time-in-scala/) if you want to do a more rigorous investigation (i.e. average over many trials, rather than 1).

Answer (score 0):

If your list isn't big, a simple `filter` as suggested by others should suffice:

```
list.filter(_ => Random.nextDouble < p)
```

In case you have a big list, the per-element call of `Random` could become the bottleneck.  One approach to minimize the calls is to generate random `gaps` (0, 1, 2, ...) by which the data sampling will hop over the elements.  Below is a simple implementation in Scala:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.math._

def gapSampling(list: List[Double], p: Double): List[Double] = {
  def randomGap(p: Double): Double = {
    val epsilon: Double = 1e-10
    val u = max(Random.nextDouble, epsilon)
    floor( log(u) / log(1 - p) )
  }

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def samplingFcn(acc: List[Double], list: List[Double], p: Double): List[Double] = list match {
    case Nil => acc
    case _ =>
      val gap = randomGap(p).toInt
      val l = list.drop(gap + 1)
      val accNew = l.headOption match {
        case Some(e) => e :: acc
        case None => acc
      }
      samplingFcn(accNew, l, p)
  }

  samplingFcn(List[Double](), list, p).reverse
}

val list = (1 to 100).toList.map(_.toDouble)

gapSampling(list, 0.3)
// res1: List[Double] = List(
//   2.0, 5.0, 7.0, 14.0, 15.0, 18.0, 20.0, 25.0, 26.0, 28.0, 33.0,
//   35.0, 42.0, 43.0, 47.0, 48.0, 50.0, 55.0, 56.0, 59.0, 62.0,
//   69.0, 72.0, 75.0, 76.0, 79.0, 82.0, 93.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0
// )
```

More details about such gap sampling can be found [here](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2014/09/11/faster-random-samples-with-gap-sampling/).